# Sharepoint 2010 development - internet sites or team sites?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am completely new to `SharePoint 2010` and have managed to install SP2010 on windows 7 as a development machine.

I am trying to develop a site from scratch on the SharePoint platform but don't understand how to get my hand the code behind the pages. I understand they are generated dynamically using the database interaction however I want to create a multistage much like `WordPress` version but using SharePoint. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to develop a multistage using `SharePoint 2010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit master pages with tools like visual studio but your shouldn't. Download and install SharePoint Designer, it is a free development environment from Microsoft that is specially built to edit the **context** items of SharePoint.

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx

If you want to build web parts and so on have a loop at the SharePoint developer tools for visual studio, but to handle this you will need to buy a book about the subject. SharePoint development becomes pretty advanced as soon as you leave the web-gui.

Comment: Since your post I have found working with SP designer very useful due to its like with SP2010 and the ease to modify code, add css style sheets and add web parts. Many thanks :)